# building url query string using n1ql

Tags: couchbase, sql++

using couchbase 5

I need to build a query string from this object

```
[
  {
    "_id": 190,
    "querystring": [
      {
        "name": "p1",
        "value": "val1"
      },
      {
        "name": "p2",
        "value": "val2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

the expected output should be

```
p1=val1&p2=val2
```

can anyone help here?

after few attempts I think I got closer to the solution I need.

```
[
  {
    "_id": 190,
    "res": [
      "company_id=$PREFIJO&",
      "user_country=$COUNTRY&",
      "offer_unique_code=$PIXEL&",
      "pub_id=$PUBID&"
    ]
  }
]
```

now, how can I convert "res" to a concatenated string of all the array elements?

Comment: Be mindful of [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding). Unless you know the values in the database are pre-encoded, you'll need to URL encode them when building the query string. @vsr might blow my mind and tell us N1QL has built-in string functions for URL encoding, but I suspect you'd need to write a [User-Defined Function](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/userfun.html). Personally, I would use N1QL only to get the JSON object, then build the query string in the application.

Comment: Well, vsr has blown my mind again :-) According to [MB-53188](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-53188) they're adding `urlencode` and `urldecode` functions to N1QL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH obj AS ({ "_id": 190, "querystring": [ { "name": "p1", "value": "val1" }, { "name": "p2", "value": "val2" } ] })
SELECT obj._id, CONCAT2("&", ARRAY CONCAT2("=",v.name,v.`value`) FOR v IN obj.querystring END) AS res;
```

Array of objects

```
WITH objs AS ([{ "_id": 190, "querystring": [ { "name": "p1", "value": "val1" }, { "name": "p2", "value": "val2" } ] },
              { "_id": 191, "querystring": [ { "name": "p3", "value": "val1" }, { "name": "p4", "value": "val2" } ] }
             ])
SELECT obj._id, CONCAT2("&", ARRAY CONCAT2("=",v.name,v.`value`) FOR v IN obj.querystring END) AS res FROM objs AS obj ;
```

Older version where CONCAT2() not available, get array of strings (name=val) and do in application or use the following technique. Assume your name/val doesn't have any replace characters.

```
WITH objs AS ([{ "_id": 190, "querystring": [ { "name": "p1", "value": "val1" }, { "name": "p2", "value": "val2" } ] },
              { "_id": 191, "querystring": [ { "name": "p3", "value": "val1" }, { "name": "p4", "value": "val2" } ] }
             ])
SELECT obj._id, replace(replace(replace(encode_json(ARRAY CONCAT(v.name,"=",v.`value`) FOR v IN obj.querystring END),"\",\"","&"),"[\"",""),"\"]","") AS res FROM objs AS obj ;
```

If single document then have ARRAY of objects then use UNNEST

If there is number , convert to string using TO_STR() before CONCAT operation

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/stringfun.html#fn-str-concat2

Comment: select c._id
, CONCAT("&", ARRAY CONCAT("=",v.name,v.`value`) FOR v IN c.publisherTokens END) AS res

....

returns res=null

the data is as follows:
[
  {
    "_id": 190,
    "publisherTokens": [
      {
        "name": "company_id",
        "value": "$PREFIJO"
      },
      {
        "name": "user_country",
        "value": "$COUNTRY"
      }
    ],
  },

Comment: You need to post complete query. It is hard to know what is FROM clause. is c is ARRAY or c is OBJECT

Comment: select c._id,
 array CONCAT(v.name,"=",v.`value`,'&') FOR v IN c.publisherTokens END
AS res
from dbname c
where c._type='Company' and array_length(c.publisherTokens)>0  
limit 10

Comment: Use CONCAT2 , not CONCAT as suggested . select c._id, CONCAT2("&", ARRAY CONCAT2("=", v.name,v.`value`) FOR v IN c.publisherTokens END) AS res from dbname c where c._type="Company" and array_length(c.publisherTokens)>0 limit 10

Comment: concat2 does not exists in version 5

Comment: In that case you can only can get ARRAY of string name=val and you need to do in application  select c._id, ARRAY CONCAT(v.name,"=",v.`value`) FOR v IN c.publisherTokens END AS res from dbname c where c._type="Company" and array_length(c.publisherTokens)>0 limit 10

Comment: select c._id, replace(replace(replace(replace(encode_json(ARRAY CONCAT(v.name,"=",v.value) FOR v IN c.publisherTokens END),",","&"),"\"",""),"[",""),"]","") AS res from dbname c where c._type="Company" and array_length(c.publisherTokens)>0 limit 10

Comment: select c._id, replace(replace(replace(encode_json(ARRAY CONCAT(v.name,"=",v.value) FOR v IN c.publisherTokens END),"\",\"","&"),"[\"",""),"\"]","") AS res from dbname c where c._type="Company" and array_length(c.publisherTokens)>0 limit 10

Comment: perfect, thanks

this is the final query...

select c._id,
replace(replace(replace(replace(encode_json(ARRAY CONCAT(v.name,"=",v.`value`) FOR v IN c.publisherTokens END),",","&"),"\"",""),"[",""),"]","") AS re
from dbname c
where c._type='Company' and array_length(c.publisherTokens)>0  
limit 10

Comment: use this 1 less replace and will reduce conflicts select c._id, replace(replace(replace(encode_json(ARRAY CONCAT(v.name,"=",v.value) FOR v IN c.publisherTokens END),"\",\"","&"),"[\"",""),"\"]","") AS res from dbname c where c._type="Company" and array_length(c.publisherTokens)>0 limit 10